# How to sign an application and a site with SSL

Tags: ssl, signing, pfx

I have a question regarding signing with SSL. I need to sign an application (.exe) written in Delphi. At the same time I also want to sign an Internet Portal with which the application communicate. My question is: does signing services generally provide also the certificate for the application either the certificate for the site? Can you sign the application with the same certificate or do you need another certificate? Can you sign multiple applications with the same certificate?

Thanks in advance.

Alberto

Comment: There is no such thing as signing with SSL. Do you mean signing with OpenSSL? Signing with an SSL *certificate?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 certificates: One for code signing (that is, signing the .exe) and one for SSL (for the website).

You can *not* sign the application using the same cert as your are using for SSL.

You can sign as many applications with your code signing certificate as you like.

You may or may not use the SSL cert for multiple hosts (e.g.: blog.domain.com, www.domain.com, chat.domina.com, static.domain.com...), this depends on the type of certificate you are using.

Also: Please note that you can get free SSL certificates (e.g.: LetsEncrypt provides them, and azure website can use free "managed" certs from microsoft.). However, to my knowledge, there are no free code signing certificates.